# Apple rechaza mi app - Error wifi IPv6 en ipad

Tags: swift, swift4, certificado-apple

He subido una app al apple store, pero apple me lo ha rechazado. Me dice lo siguiente:

> Gracias por tu nueva presentación.
>
> Descubrimos uno o más errores en su aplicación cuando revisamos en el
>   iPad con iOS 11.2.6 en Wi-Fi conectado a una red IPv6.
>
> Específicamente, su aplicación se inicia en una pantalla sin
>   contenido.

No se como solucionarlo, hice unos cambios en una función que comprueba si hay internet y se suponia que ya funcionaba en iphone, pero ahora me dicen que hay error en ipad.

¿Os ha pasado a alguno?
¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo que a ti. Todavía no me he puesto con esto, pero mira esto a ver si puedes solucionarlo y lo publicas. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

Comment: Con eso ya probé pero no me dió ningún error. Gracias de todas formas! @Spidvmp

Comment: Hola, ya les contestaste ?? usualmente te envian links de ayuda o normas, si no respondeles y preguntales como podriás solucionar tu problema. En los personal no se que estas implementando pero nunca he tenido ese problema

Comment: Me ha vuelto a pasar hace un par de semanas. Lo volví a subir sin hacer ningún cambio y me la aceptaron. Creo que si por algún motivo les falla su prueba aunque no sea por problemas de tu app, te la tiran y se quedan tan a gusto